# Teradata - if... then... depending on day of week (run different code)

Tags: if-statement, teradata, dayofweek

**Background**: I'm building a rather simple table that is simply a select * from another table that needs to select the last 3 day's worth of data if it is a Monday and the last one day's worth of data if it's Tuesday-Friday.

**Problem**: I'm not sure I understand how to do this using an IF... THEN statement.

**Code attempted**:

```
IF DAY_OF_WEEK = 2

    THEN

         SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-3 AND CURRENT_DATE

    ELSE 

         SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-1 AND CURRENT_DATE

    END IF
```

This clearly doesn't work but demonstrates the logic of what I am trying to do. Any thoughts on how I might tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

The following should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE DATE_COLUMN >= (SELECT CASE WHEN TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE) = 2 
                                   THEN CURRENT_DATE - 3 
                                   ELSE CURRENT_DATE - 1 
                              END)
   AND DATE_COLUMN <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: Hi @Rob. Very similar solution to the one above - looks like we posted at the same time. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN CASE
                   WHEN td_day_of_week(DATE) = 2 THEN DATE-3
                   WHEN td_day_of_week(DATE) BETWEEN 3 AND 6 THEN DATE-1
                   ELSE DATE+1
                   END
           AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer courtesy of Dave from Ward Analytics:

https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/IF-THEN-depending-on-day-of-week-run-different-code/m-p/75085/highlight/false#M31242